# How to select categorized value with x sequence in mysqli query

Tags: mysql, select

I have database table of news, there are three type news text, image and video.
I want to select all rows but each video post should be fetch after every two rows of text and image post.
Please try to help me to make a select mysqli query. Thanks in advance !

```
  Result in News Table


  Dbid      News_Type       Heading**
    1       text            text goes here
    2       video           text goes here
    3       image           text goes here
    4       text            text goes here
    5       video           text goes here
    6       video           text goes here
    7       image           text goes here
    8       text            text goes here
    9       text            text goes here
    10      image           text goes here
```

I want to fetch result sort with video type after two row

```
Raw Dbid    News_Type   Heading
1   1       text        text goes here
2   3       image       text goes here
3   2       video       text goes here
4   4       text        text goes here
5   7       image       text goes here
6   5       video       text goes here
7   8       text        text goes here
8   9       text        text goes here
9   6       video       text goes here
10  10      image       text goes here
```

Comment: Did you mean MySQL query? Could we see your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is i found finally

```
$query="select * from ( select ( case when news_type='video' then @a:=@a+1 when news_type='image' then @b:=@b+1 else @c:=@c+2 end) serial_number, news_type from tbl_news, (SELECT @a:=0,@b:=0,@c:=0) as t ) a order by 1,2";
```

I hope it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a rank to each record within groups of records sharing the same `news_type`, ordered by `db_id`. Then, in the outer query, you can sort by row number, and then by `news_type`:

```
SELECT 
    dbid, 
    news_type, 
    heading
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY news_type ORDER BY dbid) rn
    FROM mytable
) x
ORDER BY 
    rn, 
    CASE news_type 
        WHEN 'text'  THEN 1
        WHEN 'image' THEN 2
        WHEN 'video' THEN 3
    END
```

Note: this requires MySQL 8.0.

Note 2: if there is an uneven number of records for each news type, then you will see discrepancies at the end of the resultset.

Note 3: do you really need that first column called `raw` in the resultset, that basically assigns new row numbers? If you do, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` again in the outer query, with the same ordering clause:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
        rn, 
        CASE news_type 
            WHEN 'text'  THEN 1
            WHEN 'image' THEN 2
            WHEN 'video' THEN 3
        END
    ) raw,
    dbid, 
    news_type, 
    heading
FROM 
-- rest of the query is unchanged
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but currently not available mysql 8.0 on my host panel, can you please try to make more simple with detail explain..

Comment: @AbhijeetShinde: unfortunately I believe that this will be much harder to achieve in earlier versions of MySQL...

Comment: sort that logic in your code just order by type then id, and build a new array that have the correct order in your code.

Comment: Hello, @GMB I don't need to rawid or dbid...it was just to understand, i want just result in sequence